# Clarification regarding concatenation and union in regular expressions.

Tags: computer-science, regular-expressions

I'm just having a little trouble understanding the precedence relationship between the concatenation and union operators in regular expressions.

Specifically (for my problem), given the regular expression:

$(aa^*+ba^*)^* . (bbb+ab^*)+(ab)^*$

Would it be correct to treat the order of operation as follows:

$((aa^*+ba^*)^* . (bbb+ab^*))+(ab)^*$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "the final union operator"?

Comment: I see that my description may have caused confusion. I simply wish to know if the first regular expression has an identical meaning to the second.

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate on stackoverflow. Consider deleting here and asking there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations), for regular operations is star (highest precedence), product, union. Thus you are right, $(aa^*+ba^*)^* (bbb+ab^*)+(ab)^*$ is equivalent to $((aa^*+ba^*)^* (bbb+ab^*))+(ab)^*$. Note however that you should avoid the dot in your expressions, otherwise you should also write $a \cdot a^*$ for instance.

By the way, this is the same precedence order than for the three operations exponent, product, sum for numbers.